# After booting up my laptop, and connecting to network server, my screen freezes, if I do not connect to server, no screen freeze!

Tags: network-manager, lock-screen

I get locked screen, or a frozen screen moments after starting up my laptop, and connecting to the network server. If I do not connect to network, the screen does not freeze, the mouse works, everything is good. What is going on? Using Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: What GPU ?
If is intel is due to some kernel bug in the latest kernel.

Comment: Yes think Intel Iris. How to get rid of bug in the kernel? After starting up only have a couple minutes active screen before everything freezes

Comment: Or, can I manually update to another kernel that doesn't exhibit problem?

Comment: You can try. For me didn't help. Try to downgrade to some 5,8 version. That is the old version used in Ubuntu as the main kernel on the release date.

Comment: the way it goes every time I start up the laptop and my wifi is connected after a few moments the screen freezes, but, if I use a bluetooth connection to my phone to the laptop I have no frozenscreen or any problems at all with laptop, got to be something in my wifi connection or network settings for my ubuntu but I cannot figure out what it is, but thankyou anyways